# Reverse odd length words from a string

Tags: java, string, for-loop, stringbuilder

I am trying to reverse the words from a **string = "One Two three Four"** whose length is odd, I am using **StringBuilder** class to reverse the words my expected output is **"enO owT eerht Four"** but I am getting **"eerht enO Two Four"** here the order is not correct also it is not reversing **"Two"**, what's wrong with my code also please provide a solution to it.

```
package QAIntvSprint;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class SecretAgent {
  static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    secretAgentII("One Two three Four");
  }

  static void secretAgentII(String s) {
    String[] arr = s.split(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].length() % 2 == 0) {
        sb.append(arr[i] + " ");
      } else {
        sb.append(arr[i]).reverse().append(" ");
      }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

output is below
[image]

Comment: This comment is for the person who voted to close this question. Your reason: "_The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem._" This question (from the beginning) included the desired behavior. It also included the specific problem AND the code necessary to reproduce the problem. You need to stop voting to close questions just because you can. It is not constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding the strings to the same instance of `StringBuilder` and reversing it as a whole. The key is to create a temporary buffer to reverse the string and once it is reversed, append the contents of the temporary buffer to the `sb` buffer.

To fix, replace the contents of the `else` block with the following snippet:

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(arr[i]).reverse();
sb.append(temp.toString()).append(" ");
```

The program now outputs

```
[One, Two, three, Four]
enO owT eerht Four
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a stream approach here:

```java
String input = "One Two three Four";
String output = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
                      .map(x -> new StringBuilder(x).reverse().toString())
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(output);  // enO owT eerht ruoF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pattern` like this.

```
static final Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("\\S+");

static String secretAgentII(String s) {
    return WORD.matcher(s)
        .replaceAll(m -> m.group().length() % 2 == 0
            ? m.group()
            : new StringBuilder(m.group()).reverse().toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(secretAgentII("One     Two three Four"));
}
```

output:

```
enO     owT eerht Four
```